# Solve Laplace-like integral

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

I need to solve the following integral:
$$I_n(s):=\frac 1 {(4\pi)^{(n-1)/2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{t^{(n-1)/2}} dt,$$
where $s = |k|^2 - iE$ clearly has $\Re(s)>0$ and $n\geq 2$. It looks a lot like a Laplace transform, but tabulated solutions are useless for the values of $n$ that I need. It can possibly be done by introducing a parameter $\varepsilon$ somewhere in the integrand and then letting $\varepsilon \to 0$, maybe via some contour integration, but all my attempts have led nowhere (I tried, e.g., introducing it in the denominator $t\mapsto(t+\varepsilon)$ and then changing variable, but the calculation quickly became unfeasible). How should I proceed?

Comment: The integral diverges for $n\geqslant 3$ because near $0$, the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{t^{(n-1)/2}}$.

Comment: For $n<3$, enforce the substitution $t\mapsto t/s$.  Then use the definition of the Gamma function.